Bad mui table display
I use Table from @mui/material and  follow https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/
For reproducible issue, I do a static table with fixed values.
I do
            <TableContainer>
              <Table sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>test</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Required</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>foo</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>bar</TableCell>
                   <TableCell>baz</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>

But table rendering is wrong. The expected rendering is the cell value "bar" in the column "name".

React Snippet


const { useState, userEffect, StrictMode } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

const {
  TableContainer, 
  Table, 
  TableHead,
  TableBody, 
  TableRow, 
  TableCell
  } = window.MaterialUI;


    root.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>
    );


    function App() {
        return (
        <div className="App">
      <TableContainer>
      <h3>Packages</h3>
      <Table sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>test</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Required</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>foo</TableCell>
            <TableCell>bar</TableCell>
           <TableCell>baz</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
        </div>
        );
    }
<div id="root"></div>
<!-- React 18 -->
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5.0.0/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>



Snippet works as expected but not into my app.
I don't inderstand what is wrong

Issue is the same with 3 columns into TableBody

It's from "@mui/material not window.MaterialUI

Check the css. May be some css is getting applied to Header row or Header cells

I fix it, It was a css issue ...
I remove display: "block" property and table indentation is fixed !

If you fixed it, please share the solution with the community.
